# Reading 1D barcodes using zxing for iPhone

Tags: iphone, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

is there a way to read 1d barcodes using zxing for iPhone? The zxing's homepage says it can only be used for QR Codes but has anyone ported 1D barcode scanning to iPhone or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See *Why don't 1D codes work on iOS devices?* in the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) (which, FWIW, I wrote).

There are ports of 1D decoders but while there is lots of interest, no one has stepped up to maintain them. They're out of date with respect to the Java decoders which shows in their lower accuracy on the ZXing test set.

Comment: I don't understand from anywhere if porting the java 1d bar scanner library code to cpp for iPhone, is a lot of work.. or just few classes to convert. Can you help me to find out this ?

Comment: It's a moderate amount of work. For someone moderately familiar with Java and C++ (not expert, but more or less comfortable) it's a few days work, maybe?

Comment: Thanks. After posting my last comment, Ive found out that I actually need to use scanners for UPC-A and UPC-EAN barcodes. Ive seen there are only 3 classes related to these barcodes scanners and the java version looks si ilr to the cpp versions. Does this simplify a lot the porting in my case, or there are other core library classes who needs to be updated as well?

Comment: I don't think it'd be too hard. Many of the core classes are used in other code and so should be up to date. There is the caveat that there's a fair amount of derivation in the 1D codes so you'd need to make sure all the base classes are in sync (though it sounds like you might have already checked that).